# How to show dimension values in scaled points

Tags: tex-core, dimensions

TeX stores dimensions internally in scaled points but operation `\the` expands to the corresponding value in points.  Can we avoid the conversion and get the more precise, "original" value instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ tex \\relax
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=tex)

*
(Please type a command or say `\end')
*\dimen0=3.5in

*\showthe\dimen0
> 252.94499pt.
<*> \showthe\dimen0

? 

*\count0=\dimen0

*\showthe\count0
> 16577003.
<*> \showthe\count0
```

dimen values are just integer values interpreted as `sp` so you can do the above (although actually there is no loss of precision I think in the fractional `pt` value tex shows, it always shows enough decimal places to determine the exact value in `sp`)

Comment: If e-TeX is available, `\showtokens\expandafter{\number\dimen0}` avoids assigning the value to a count register. In general `\number\dimen0` will expand the dimension in scaled points (with possible number termination problems, of course).

Comment: This was an easy question :-) But how about dimension values in the output file? Can we have them in scaled points, too?

Comment: @egreg What are number termination problems?

Comment: @AngelTsankov Don't worry: leave a space after `\dimen0` and you'll be OK.

Comment: @egreg so modern, as always, I forget the 1980's have finished.

Comment: @AngelTsankov It depends what is putting dimensions in the log. If it is a message originating in macros you can basically do the above and then `\typeout{\the\count@..` instead of `\typeout{\the\dimen@...` but if you mean lengths coming from the tex engine such as overfull box warnings then no, they are always in pt.

Answer (score 7):

For printing a length in `sp` units, define

```
\newcommand\lengthinsp[1]{\number\dimexpr#1\relax sp}
```

This will accept `\lengthinsp{\parindent}` (with a register) or even `\lengthinsp{3.5in}`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\lengthinsp[1]{\number\dimexpr#1\relax sp}

\begin{document}

\lengthinsp{\parindent}

\lengthinsp{3.5in}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is fully expandable. If you don't want to depend on e-TeX, a non-expandable version is needed:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lengthinsp}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \dimen@=#1\relax
  \number\dimen@ sp%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```